# How to export google cloud monitoring graphs of compute instance programmatically through GCP Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am developing a telegram bot with some default commands , deploying it using Google cloud functions to export metrics , graphs of **compute engine instance** where i hosted a web application.

Eg:
/health
/graphs
/uptime

Idea is that Google cloud function will call some gcp api to get the details programmatically either using REST or GRPC ( in golang) related to compute instance.

**Question:**

- Is it possible to export the graphs , dashboards , uptime , other monitoring information related to compute engine when the google cloud function is invoked from Telegram ?

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi, In this case I would suggest to get the data points using [Monitoring Library](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) and then graph that data points.